# Show that the equation has exactly one solution on $[1, 2]$,then find the solution correct to $4$ decimal places using Newton’s method

Tags: functions, derivatives, newton-raphson

*Show that the equation $^3 + 2 = 5$ has exactly one solution on $[1, 2]$. Then find the solution correct to $4$ decimal places using
Newton’s method.*

Looking at the problem, I wonder how do I finish this problem without using the initial guess, but I can't seem to figure it out. I have absolutely no idea on how to finish this problem.

Comment: Let $f(x) = x^3+2x-5$. Note that $f(1)<0, f(2)>0$. Show that $f$ is strictly increasing on $[1,2]$.

Comment: Thanks! Really helped me a lot with this problem.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Take the derivative to show the function is increasing monotonically. The note the function starts negative at the beginning and reaches a positive value at the end. So by the Intermediate Value Theorem, it must hit zero somewhere on the interval. It can do this only once since it is increasing.

From there you can use Newtons Method or the cubic formula. 1 is probably a good starting point.

Comment: Thanks! But I think we should prove the function is strictly increasing instead of monotonically as the question asked to prove there is exactly one solution.

Comment: @Randomperson If $f(x)=0$ has more than one solution, $f$ has to both strictly increase and strictly decrease between two solutions. No need to check that it's strictly increasing. Just increasing is enough. Not that it is any more difficult to check one than the other.